# Change format of manual equation tags without changing format of automatic numbered tags or references

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, labels

I would like to make it so that when I use the `\tag` command to give an equation a name rather than a number, this name is printed in bold next to the equation (without parentheses), but subsequent references to that equation print the name in normal font.

I tried the `\newtagform` command from package `mathtools`, but it does not do exactly what I want. It lets me change all the displayed tags (automatic equation numbers as well as manually added names) to bold.  I could put `\usetagform{bold}` before every equation with a `\tag` and `\usetagform{default}` afterwards, but this is awkward, and besides it does not work when a `gather` or `align` environment contains both a named equation (whose tag should be bold) and a numbered one (whose tag should be in the normal font).

I also tried making a custom command that does `\tag{\bfseries #1}` and then `\def@currentlabel{#1}`, but this doesn't work because of the way the `amsmath` redefines the `\label` command.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
e&=mc^2 \tag{Einstein's Equation} \label{einstein}
\\
m &= \frac{e}{c^2} \label{meinstein}
\end{align}
Notice that \ref{meinstein} is a trivial consequence of \ref{einstein}.
\end{document}
```

Desired output:[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code defines a new tag format `Cian` named after you. It detects if the label has a letter in it and then applies corresponding style.

This means, however, that for your equations in appendices, numbered as `A.1` (which contains a letter), you should switch back to the normal tag format.

Also, to get the word "equation", here I use the package `cleveref` (independent of the tag format). Of course you can also manually write this word, it is up to you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \CianFormat { m }
  {
    \regex_match:nnTF { [A-Za-z] } { #1 }
      { \textbf{#1} }
      { (#1) }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtagform{Cian}[\CianFormat]{}{}

\begin{document}

\usetagform{Cian}

\begin{align}
e&=mc^2 \tag{Einstein's Equation} \label{einstein}
\\
m &= \frac{c^2}{e} \label{meinstein}
\end{align}
Notice that \cref{meinstein} is a trivial consequence of \ref{einstein}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that does the job!  I wouldn't have thought of using a regex.  (Note that on my system I have to add `\usepackage{xparse}` for your code to compile.)